# What happens when your created thread is using more memory than the default allocated stack size?

Tags: linux, multithreading, .net-core, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to understand the thread stack allocation limits. I set the limit to 50 Kb using ulimit -s 50 and run the following program:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() => {
                DownloadImage();
            });

            thread.Start();
        
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void DownloadImage()
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
        
            using var file = await client.GetStreamAsync("some url with 1 MB file", CancellationToken.None);
        
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        
            var memoryBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"File has {memoryBytes.Length} bytes.");
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the program to throw a stack overflow exception since memoryBytes variable occupies 1MB memory from the thread stack. But the program runs fine, no exception is thrown. Why is that? Is dotnet core modifying that limit at runtime?

Comment: MemoryStream contains a reference to a buffer that is 1MB in length, it is not 1MB in size itself.

Comment: A C# array has a fixed size reference on the stack and dynamic data from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays and memory stream are reference types therefore they are allocated on the heap not on the stack. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/